# MySql - Time Scheduling query

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a table with `id, user_id, start_date_time, end_date_time`

User_id has many records. I need to search a time between Start_date_time and End_date_time of multiple records from the user_id. Example

```
1,28,2019-11-16 18:00:00, 2019-11-16 20:00:00
2,28,2019-11-17 22:00:00, 2019-11-17 23:10:00
3,28,2019-11-17 23:00:00, 2019-11-17 23:15:00
```

If i search at any given time, i need an output of all records greater than given time.

So if i need a record above 2019-11-17 22:15:00 I need the output of 2 records.

Can you help me with an example.

Comment: are those times actual TIMESTAMP or DATETIME columns, or strings?

Comment: @DanielFarrell it DATETIME

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from t
where t.end_date_time > ?;
```

The `?` is a parameter placeholder for the value you are passing in.

Comment: But the issue is i have datetime range on every record start_date_time  - end_date_time if i use the above it gives all dates it don't checks the range.

Comment: @StephenPaulraj your question lacks clarity, it says "If i search at any given time, i need an output of all records greater than given time." (Gordon answered) but also says  "I need to search a time between Start_date_time and End_date_time"

Comment: @DanielFarrell - I have 3 records for a user_id in a DATETIME range. `1,28,2019-11-16 18:00:00, 2019-11-16 20:00:00
2,28,2019-11-17 22:00:00, 2019-11-17 23:10:00
3,28,2019-11-17 23:00:00, 2019-11-17 23:15:00` I need to book an appointment for the user id `28` on `28,2019-11-17 22:35:00` - I need a all records between `28,2019-11-17 22:00:00` to `2019-11-17 23:15:00` i.e 2 records

Answer (score 0):

If you want the *inclusive* range you can use `BETWEEN`:

```
select * from times 
 WHERE cast('2019-11-17 22:15:00' as datetime) 
       between `start_date_time` and `end_date_time`;
```

If you don't want to include the start and end times in the range, you can use two comparisons `>` and `<`:

```
select * from times 
 where cast('2019-11-17 22:15:00' as datetime) > start_date_time 
 AND   cast('2019-11-17 22:15:00' as datetime) < end_date_time;
```

> So if i need a record above 2019-11-17 22:15:00 I need the output of 2 records.

Only one row matches the date you gave, for what it's worth; #2.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bPk1CYioL6cVasStZKzQ4j/2

Comment: Daniel thanks for your help, pls look again into [link]https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bPk1CYioL6cVasStZKzQ4j/6 the query #2 returns with no result. And Query #1 returns only one result instead of multiple between records.

Comment: @StephenPaulraj, it's because no rows match your WHERE clause, `where cast('2019-11-17 23:12:00' as datetime) > start_date_time 
 AND   cast('2019-11-17 23:59:00' as datetime) < end_date_time;`.  Note you have 2 different times there.

Comment: My question is i have multiple times ranges on every record during a same date. the problem is looking through every record ranges. on the fiddle id 3,4,5 has same date with different time range. What if i need all records greater than the  `2019-11-17 23:01:00`

Comment: I think you should write a new post with your _real_ question, if this post isn't it.